# Why are the remove and add methods not working in the other public class?

Tags: java, jpanel

Why are the remove and add methods not working in the other public class?

This is a Java program aimed for displaying the periodic table of elements, and upon clicking each element symbol, a new window opens up to display its properties.

The public class 'Atomic Number', which extends JFrame and implements MouseListener, opens up a window displaying the periodic table. Each element is represented by a JRadioButton object.

The public class 'Properties', which extends JFrame, opens up another window displaying an image of properties of each element. Each image is represented by a JLabel ImageIcon object.

The problem is that the image remains unchanged after clicking another element. When clicking H(Hydrogen), the properties of Hydrogen will be displayed, but when clicking He(Helium), the properties of Hydrogen are still displayed. When clicking He(Helium), how do I change the image to the properties of Helium, etc.?

[image]
This is the result of clicking H(Hydrogen).

[image]
This is the result of clicking He(Helium). Both show the properties of Hydrogen.

//main method public class

```
public class PeriodicTable {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new AtomicNumber();
  }
}
```

//public class AtomicNumber

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.swing.*;

public class AtomicNumber extends JFrame implements MouseListener {
  JRadioButton[] element;
  AtomicNumber() {
      element = new JRadioButton[119];
      element[1] = new JRadioButton("1");
      element[1].setBounds(50, 75, 50, 50);
      elementImage[1] = new ImageIcon(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("H.png"));
      properties[1] = new JLabel();
      element[2] = new JRadioButton("2");
      element[2].setBounds(925, 75, 50, 50);
      elementImage[2] = new ImageIcon(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("He.png"));
```

//this part of the code has been omitted for minimalism.

```
}
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

  new Properties();

  if (e.getSource() == element[1]) {
    new Properties().setVisible(true);
  } else if (e.getSource() == element[2]) {
```

//these remove and add methods do not work

```
**Properties.propertiesPanel.remove(properties[1]);
Properties.propertiesPanel.add(properties[2]);**

    Properties.propertiesPanel.revalidate();
    Properties.propertiesPanel.repaint();

    new Properties().setVisible(true);

  }
}
```

//public class Properties

```
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Properties extends JFrame {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1 L;

  public JLabel[] properties;
  public JPanel propertiesPanel;
  Properties() {
    properties = new JLabel[119];
    properties[1] = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("H_properties.png")));
    properties[2] = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("He_properties.png")));

    propertiesPanel = new JPanel();
    propertiesPanel.add(properties[1]);
    this.add(propertiesPanel);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setResizable(false);
    this.setSize(1250, 340);

  }
}
```

Comment: You can debug and check where the control lands up ! Probably looks like issue with setting data to correct place !

Comment: @Harsh Thanks for the comment. However, I had debugged the program and compiled it successfully without any runtime error before publishing this question. I am not sure how to change the contents of the new JFrame, could you show me how to do it?